# Как собрать анимацию из кусков с JS?

Tags: javascript, анимация

Давно зрела мысля сделать небольшую браузерную игру, вот пытаюсь залезть в тему gamedev. 
Изначально была идея сделать анимацию построенную на спрайтах:

[image]

Тут особо с проблемами не столкнулся, однако очень поплыл на идее о том, как кастомизировать персонажа (к примеру поменять вещи, оружие, усы и тп).

Тогда пришел к тому, что персонаж может состоять из отдельных частей:

[image]

И иметь некий файл с координатами для работы скелетной анимации. Я нашел несколько программ, как можно делать анимацию из нарисованного персонажа, но очень тяжко в этом плате  с JS. Есть ли какие-то инструменты подобной работы?

Comment: можете попробовать [spine js](https://spine.github.io/)

Comment: Полезные книги: 1) https://www.pdfdrive.com/pro-html5-games-learn-to-build-your-own-games-using-html5-and-javascript-e158220357.html,  2) https://www.pdfdrive.com/build-your-own-2d-game-engine-and-create-great-web-games-using-html5-javascript-and-webgl-e166780734.html,

Comment: еще:   3) https://www.pdfdrive.com/the-essential-guide-to-html5-using-games-to-learn-html5-and-javascript-e176312816.html,  4) https://www.pdfdrive.com/drawing-basics-and-video-game-art-classic-to-cutting-edge-art-techniques-for-winning-video-game-design-e158219174.html,  5) https://www.pdfdrive.com/foundation-game-design-with-html5-and-javascript-e38455809.html,  6) https://www.pdfdrive.com/web-animation-using-javascript-develop-design-e25729884.html,  7) https://www.pdfdrive.com/html5-game-development-insights-e23305689.html,

Comment: 8) https://www.pdfdrive.com/html5-games-most-wanted-build-the-best-html5-games-e168808858.html.